# Form: let user select their country (drop-down) and get the currency (php)

Tags: php, arrays, forms, country-codes

Currently I'm writing a short survey (html form) using php, mysql and jquery. I want the user to select their country from a drop-down list and then get the right currency (server side) so later on I can ask things referring to the right currency.

I really don't got a clear view on how to achieve this. I know I can find an up to date country list from: http://www.iso.org/iso/country_codes/iso_3166_code_lists.htm
I could make into a php array but then?

http://snipplr.com/view/36437/php-country-code--to-html-currency-symbol-list/
Seems nice code, but I like to use something that is up to date.

Its no problem for me to use a mysql database, but it is a problem to install plug-ins/expansions (hosting won't allow it).

Does somebody knows a good (and maybe easy) way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use CURL or file_get_contents() to read the content from the URL and is always updated.

Comment: maybe that could work for the http://www.iso.org/iso/list-en1-semic-3.txt ? would be nice

Answer (score 0):

Not answering your question, but:

As of PHP5.3 the [intl](http://php.net/intl) became a default. It contains [NumberFormatter::formatCurrency()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.formatcurrency.php) that does what your linked country_currency() is trying to do - only properly. If PHP5.3 is a viable minimum requirement (seeing that 5.2 is deprecated and not supported anymore) - use the intl functions.

With [Locale::acceptFromHttp()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/locale.acceptfromhttp.php) you can check the browser's request headers to preselect the best matching locale.

Your ISO CountryCode list should still be helpful for a manual `<select>` on a certain level. But keep in mind that it's not quite accurate: Germany translates to `de`, which may not be specific enough seeing `de_AT`, `de_CH`, `de_DE`. Each of them may present Currency differently. `€1,123.23`, `1 123,23 €`, and so on. You'll still need to know which currency you're processing, though. So you need the list of ISO country codes AND the map of countrycode to currency.

Answer (score 0):

PHP Intl's NumberFormatter accepts English as a language for any country. So just use `en_` plus your country code.

```php
echo (new NumberFormatter('en_DE', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY))
    ->getTextAttribute(NumberFormatter::CURRENCY_CODE); // EUR

echo (new NumberFormatter('en_RS', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY))
    ->getTextAttribute(NumberFormatter::CURRENCY_CODE); // RSD
```