# Country-Currency mapping in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, localization, currency, intl

In the Symfony Intl bundle, there exists a method to get the list of all currencies. Is there any way to get the mapping between a country and the currencies used in this country?

e.g.
I want to get the list of currencies used in Serbia.

Comment: I don't think it is a job of PHP..

Comment: Whose job is it then?

Comment: look at this response: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8325456/1398357

Comment: I know `Intl::getCurrencyBundle()->getCurrencyName()` or 'Intl::getCurrencyBundle()->getCurrencyNames()' can return country's currency code, but it doesn't know what other currencies are also used.

Comment: Please refer to this question which has valid answers: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38740387/2106834.

Answer (score 3):

Code:

```
echo (new NumberFormatter(
    Zend_Locale::getLocaleToTerritory('RS'),
    NumberFormatter::CURRENCY
))->getTextAttribute(NumberFormatter::CURRENCY_CODE);
```

Output:

```
RSD
```

As you can see, I used [Zend Locale](https://packagist.org/packages/zf1/zend-locale).

Greetings from Serbia. :)

Comment: NumberFormatter accepts English as a language for any country. So just use `en_` plus your country code.